# Does DOMContentLoaded closing tag always have to be at the end of doc?

Tags: javascript, domcontentloaded

Is there a way to get JavaScript code to work without having to encompass my code in a closing tag of DOMContentLoaded. The first example below does not work because the closing tag for DOMContentLoaded is before the code.

I'm worried I'm going about this the wrong way because once my code grows to a few hundred lines intuitively it feels wrong to have all of it inside this function? Is there a more efficient way in which I do not have to keep all of my code in such a function but still allow the page to load before proceeding to the enclosed code which as I understand it is the purpose of the DOMContentLoaded?

I have attempted numerous types of JavaScript queries and event listeners but still it does not work unless everything is enclosed in the DOMContentLoaded.

```
// **Example 1 - this code works after DOMContentLoaded**
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
})

// **the below code does not run**
document.querySelector("button").onclick = count;

let counter = 0;

function count() {

counter++;
document.querySelector("#counter").innerHTML = counter;
}


// example 2 - this code work
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

document.querySelector("button").onclick = count;

let counter = 0;

function count() {

  counter++;
  document.querySelector("#counter").innerHTML = counter;
}
// **If my code was large I feel that this cannot be a very efficient** 
// **way to have put it all within the DOMContentLoaded closing tag**

})   // **DOMContentLoaded closing tag**
```

Comment: Just break it up in to smaller sub functions and call them from within your contentLoaded handler

Comment: The order they appear isn't important, the order they're called is.

Comment: Note that the only stuff that has to go inside the content loaded event handler is stuff that depends on the content being loaded; so you could declare `count` and `counter` outside of the event handler, and then all the event handler has to do is the `button.onclick = count` line

Comment: Thank you will Jenkins and Hamms, I now understand fully.

Answer (score 0):

I now come to understand that the part of the code that needs to be within the DOMContentLoaded function are the calls to other functions which rely on an initial action to be taken from the web page which requires it to be fully loaded.

I also understand that other JavaScript can be run and shown to the user without the function or function call being within the Dom function. Such as alert() because it doesn’t rely on elements from the HTML page being loaded beforehand.

Thank you for your help Jenkins and Hamms.